# Concave triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, noneuclidean-geometry

I know that in Euclidean and (I think) Spherical geometries don't have concave triangles, but is there any set of axioms that would allow this?

Comment: What do you mean by a  concave triangle?

Comment: I guess the borders would be generated by the intersection of three circles.

Comment: @Woodface A concave triangle would have one of its angle pointing inwards. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons)

Comment: I can't picture that.

Comment: @GregoryGrant that's my point, is it possible, because at first thought it doesn't seem so but from my understanding there can be weird things in other geometry.

Comment: Ona sphere any convex triangle is also a concave triangle.

Comment: @EmilioNovati what do you mean by that

Comment: It depend by how you define a trangle. If it is a region of limited area delimited by three segment of ''stright line'', then the region that we usually consider the ''exterior'' of a spherical triangle may be also a triangle.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Oh I understand. Assuming that the exterior is a triangle, the old triangle's angles are the same angles as the exterior's and all the angles are pointing inward, assuming the interior triangle is the smaller.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. But I don't know if it is really an answer or simply a joke.